# Apache with PHP-FPM not working

Tags: apache-2.4, php5

I am following [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/using-php5-fpm-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/apache-2-4-with-php5-fpm) article to setup **apache2** and **php5-fpm** under Ubuntu 14.04, but it always return a **HTTP 403** when I run `phpinfo()`, how do I fix it?

I didn't edit the virtual host configuration file, but I add a file under `/etc/apache2/conf-available` call `php5-fpm.conf`.

php5-fpm.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
    Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
    FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had found a [tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache/running-fastcgi-php-fpm-on-debian-7-with-apache) that fix the permission problem. I use Ubuntu but this tutorial still works.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to run to make it working:

```
a2enconf php7.4-fpm
```

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/enable-http-2-apache-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Thanks for the link, I needed to run `sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi` so that the proxy worked.